# Прикрепить ссылку к attachments в метод wall.post в vk

Tags: php, ооп, vkontakte-api

Не получается прикрепить ссылку в конце поста в VK через vk api методом `wall.post` в параметре `attachments`.

```
 // загрузка фото на сервер
$attachments = $v->upload_photo(0, array('img/1.jpg'));

// публикация на стене

$response = $v->api('wall.post', array(
    'owner_id' => -xxxxxx,
    'message'=>'я публикую фотографии',
    'attachments' => implode(',', $attachments)
  )
```

Пробовал разными способами добавить в массив `attachments` строку со ссылкой, после чего нет ни ссылки ни изображения остается только сообщение.

Вот сам класс V:

`

- Class Vk
- @author: Dmitriy Nyashkin
- @link: https://github.com/fdcore/vk.api
- @version: 2

class VkException extends Exception {};

class Vk{

```
private $v = '5.35'; // версия Api VKontakte @link https://vk.com/dev/versions
const VERSION = '2.0'; // версия этой библиотеки

const CALLBACK_BLANK = 'https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html';
const AUTHORIZE_URL  = 'https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?';
const GET_TOKEN_URL  = 'https://oauth.vk.com/access_token?';
const METHOD_URL     = 'https://api.vk.com/method/';

public $secret_key  = null;
public $scope       = array();
public $client_id   = null;
public $access_token= null;
public $owner_id    = 0;
private $_api_scope = '';

/**
 * Это Конструктор (Кэп.)
 * Передаются параметры настроек
 * @param array $options
 */
function __construct( $options = array()){

    $this->scope[]='offline'; // обязательно запрашиваем права на оффлайн работу без участия пользователя

    $this->set_options($options);
}

// Magic Method (*__*)
function __call($method, $params){
    if(!isset($params[0])) $params[0] = array();
    return $this->api($this->_api_scope . '.' . $method, $params[0]);
}

function  __get($name){
    $this->_api_scope = $name;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Выполнение вызова Api метода
 * @param string $method - метод, http://vk.com/dev/methods
 * @param array $vars - параметры метода
 * @return array - выводит массив данных или ошибку (но тоже в массиве)
 */
public function api($method = '', array $vars = array()){

    $vars['v']            = $this->v;
    $vars['access_token'] = $this->access_token;

    $params = http_build_query($vars);
    $url    = $this->http_build_query($method, $params);

    return $this->call($url);
}

public function execute($code){
    return $this->api('execute', array('code' => $code));
}

/**
 * Построение конечного URI для выхова
 * @param $method
 * @param string $params
 * @return string
 */
private function http_build_query($method, $params = ''){
    return  self::METHOD_URL . $method . '?' . $params;
}

/**
 * Получить ссылка на запрос прав доступа
 *
 * @param string $type тип ответа (code - одноразовый код авторизации , token - готовый access token)
 * @param string callback url
 * @return mixed
 */
public function get_code_token( $type  = "token", $callback = self::CALLBACK_BLANK ){

    $url = self::AUTHORIZE_URL;
    $url .= http_build_query(array(
        'response_type' => $type,
        'client_id'     => $this->client_id,
        'redirect_uri'  => $callback,
        'display'       => 'page',
        'version'       => $this->v,
        'scope'         => implode(',', $this->scope),
    ));

    return $url;
}

public function get_access_token($code, $callback = self::CALLBACK_BLANK ){

    $url = self::GET_TOKEN_URL;

    $url .= http_build_query(array(
        'code'          => $code,
        'client_id'     => $this->client_id,
        'redirect_uri'  => $callback,
        'client_secret' => $this->secret_key,
        'version'       => $this->v,
        'scope'         => implode(',', $this->scope),
    ));

    return $this->call($url);
}

private function call($url = ''){

    if(function_exists('curl_init')) $json = $this->curl_post($url); else $json = file_get_contents($url);

    $json = json_decode($json, true);

    // Произошла ошибка на стороне VK, коды ошибок тут https://vk.com/dev/errors
    if(isset($json['error'], $json['error']['error_msg'], $json['error']['error_code'])){

        throw new VkException($json['error']['error_msg'], $json['error']['error_code']);
    }

    if(isset($json['response'])) return $json['response'];

    return $json;
}

/*
  Send cURL POST request
*/
private function curl_post($url){

    if(!function_exists('curl_init')) return false;

    $param = parse_url($url);

    if( $curl = curl_init() ) {

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $param['scheme'].'://'.$param['host'].$param['path']);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $param['query']);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER ,false);

        $out = curl_exec($curl);

        curl_close($curl);

        return $out;
    }

    return false;
}

/**
 * @param array $options
 */
public function set_options($options = array()){

    if(count($options) > 0){
        foreach($options as $key => $value){
            if($key == 'scope' && is_string($value)){
                $_scope = explode(',', $value);
                $this->scope = array_merge($this->scope, $_scope);
            } else {
                $this->$key = $value;
            }

        }
    }

}

/**
 * @param bool $gid
 * @param array $files
 * @param bool (TRUE = вернуть список id файлов | FALSE = вернуть массив аттачей для прикрепления)
 * @return array|bool
 */
public function upload_photo($gid = 0, $files = array(), $return_ids = false){

    if(count($files) == 0) return false;
    if(!function_exists('curl_init')) return false;

    $data_json = $this->api('photos.getWallUploadServer', array('group_id'=> intval($gid)));

    if(!isset($data_json['upload_url'])) return false;

    $temp = array_chunk($files, 4); // лимит файлов

    $files = array();
    $attachments = array();

    foreach ($temp[0] as $key => $data) {
        $path = realpath($data);

        if($path){
          $files['file' . ($key+1)] = (class_exists('CURLFile', false)) ? new CURLFile(realpath($data)) : '@' . realpath($data);
        }
    }

    $upload_url = $data_json['upload_url'];

    $ch = curl_init($upload_url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: multipart/form-data"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;)");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $files);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    $upload_data = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);

    $upload_data['group_id'] = intval($gid);

    $response = $this->api('photos.saveWallPhoto', $upload_data);

    if(count($response) > 0){

        foreach($response as $photo){

            if($return_ids)
                $attachments[] = $photo['id'];
            else
                $attachments[] = 'photo'.$photo['owner_id'].'_'.$photo['id'];
        }
    }

    return $attachments;

}

/**
 * Заливка документа (например GIF файл)
 *
 * @param bool $gid
 * @param $file
 * @return bool|string
 */
public function upload_doc($gid = false, $file){

    if(!is_string($file)) return false;
    if(!function_exists('curl_init')) return false;

    $data_json = $this->api('docs.getUploadServer', array('gid'=> intval($gid)));

    var_dump($data_json);

    if(!isset($data_json['upload_url'])) return false;

    $attachment = false;

    $path = realpath($file);

    if(!$path) return false;

    $files['file'] = (class_exists('CURLFile', false)) ? new CURLFile($file) : '@' . $file;

    $upload_url = $data_json['upload_url'];

    $ch = curl_init($upload_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: multipart/form-data"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;)");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $files);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    $upload_data = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);

    $response = $this->api('docs.save', $upload_data);

    if(count($response) > 0){

        foreach($response as $photo){

            $attachment = 'doc'.$photo['owner_id'].'_'.$photo['did'];
        }
    }

    return $attachment;

}

/**
 *
 * Заливка видео
 *
 * http://vk.com/dev/video.save
 *
 * @param array $options
 * @param bool $file
 * @return bool|string
 */
public function upload_video($options = array(), $file = false){

    if(!is_array($options)) return false;
    if(!function_exists('curl_init')) return false;

    $data_json = $this->api('video.save', $options);

    if(!isset($data_json['upload_url'])) return false;

    $attachment = 'video'.$data_json['owner_id'].'_'.$data_json['video_id'];

    $upload_url = $data_json['upload_url'];
    $ch = curl_init($upload_url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: multipart/form-data"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;)");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    // если указан файл то заливаем его отправкой POST переменной video_file
    if($file && file_exists($file)){
        //@todo надо протестировать заливку
        $path = realpath($file);

        if(!$path) return false;

        $files['video_file'] = (class_exists('CURLFile', false)) ? new CURLFile($file) : '@' . $file;

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $files);
        curl_exec($ch);

    // иначе просто обращаемся по адресу (ну надо так!)
    } else {

        curl_exec($ch);
    }

    return $attachment;

}

/**
 * Загружает видео из массива ссылок
 *
 * @param array $videos — массив ссылок на видео (youtube/vimeo)
 * @return array — массив загруженных видео (прикреплений) для использования при постинге
 */
public function uploadVideosFromArray(array $videos){

    $attached_videos = array();
    foreach($videos as $i => $video_url) {
        $attached_videos[] = $this->upload_video(array('link' => $video_url,'wallpost' => 0));

    }

    return $attached_videos;
}
```

}

`

Comment: а где сам класс `$v` ?

Comment: читайте внимательно документацию!!! `Данный метод доступен только Standalone-приложениям и web-приложениям, использующим окно подтверждения.`...... окно подтверждения используют `ClientAPI, OpenAPI и SDK,`  https://vk.com/dev/api_confirm  ...........вы же пытаетесь на сервере манипулировать... логично что аттача не может быть

Comment: сам метод у меня работает! сообщение и изображение постится на стенку в группе! но когда я пытаюсь уже к существующему attachment добавить в конце ссылку как сказано в инструкции к данному методу, то пропадает все кроме сообщения! (исчезает изображение из поста)